# Using mercurial to work on a project online?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I was just wondering what my options are when it comes to hosting and working on a repository online with some friends. I'm currently using TortoiseHG, Mercurial for Windows. I'm just beginning to use version control, so apologies in advance if this is a noob question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) offers free public and private repositories.